# zpool replace fails

Tags: zfs

trying to replace a bad disk in a mirrored zfs pool. Published commands do not work

My error

zpool replace extra /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E7KS505J-part1 /dev/sdk
/dev/sdk is in use and contains a unknown filesystem.
taichi:~:5007#

the WD disk is bad and have already been swapped.
The new disk is /dev/sdk

I want to add it back to the mirror and resilver

Comment: also the umount fails             taichi:~:5002> sudo umount /dev/sdk                                        (32)
umount: /dev/sdk: not mounted.
taichi:~:5003>

Comment: zpool replace extra /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E7KS505J-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E1XS4R90
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E1XS4R90 is in use and contains a unknown filesystem.
taichi:~:5016#

Comment: my home directory is on the GOOD disk so that complicates things  (dev/sdj is good)  I want to add the newly replaced /dev/sdk to replace the old dead /dev/sdk - the good drive has already been installed

Comment: zdb output for mirror

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the drive letters switched - old bad was /dev/sdk replaced with new good and became /dev/sdj and old was /dev/sdk - went and looked AGAIN by id and saw it.